# Best approach of search users based on distance in php,mysql and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am building a community website. Where I need to search user’s profile according to distance. For example I live in city London my location’s longitude and latitude are 0.2 and -1.2 now I want to run a mysql query which show me users profile order by distance from me so first I will see all users from London and then nearby city and then nearby country so on.

I google I got one mysql query:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( latitude - 52.58 ) , 2 ) + 
POW( 69.1 * ( - 1.12 - longitude ) * COS( latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) AS distance 
FROM location ORDER BY distance
```

Now the problem I am facing is some people says that doing this way will be slow once you will have 100,000 users or more to search. Is there any optimal solution available for this?

Comment: These slides may be helpful: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL . They provide several ways of calculating the distance - choose what works best for you.